# Digit value to array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have number `8939`, then I want to get the array `[8000,7000,6000,5000,4000,3000,2000,1000]` and example if I have `340` then I can get the array `300,200,100`.

I just knew that , if I user

```
i = i/1000 * 1000
```

Then I can round down 8939 to 8000, but I don't know how can I got the result that I want above.

Comment: What does "get the array of the number" mean?

Comment: I'm sorry, my bad. I edited.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You may want to start with the JavaScript Math.log() function; that gives a logarithmic value that will give you (in simple terms) the number of zeros that you need in each value of your array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No reason to complicate it, you can use a `for` loop

```
function getArrForNum(num){
   var arr = []; // create a new array
   var digitNum = num.toString().length; //get the number of digits, can use Math.log instead
   var mulOf10 = Math.pow(10,digitNum-1);
   for(var i=1;i*mulOf10 < num;i++){
       arr.push(i*mulOf10); // push the next multiple of 1000
   }
   return arr; //return it
}
```

Then you can use it:

```
getArrForNum(3211); //1000,2000,3000
getArrForNum(321); //100,200,300
```

Here is a one line version just for the challenge, but I strongly suggest avoiding it :)

```
Array(+(832+"")[0]).join(".").split(".").map(function(_,i){ return (i+1)*Math.pow(10,(832+"").length-1);}); // 800,700,600,500,400,300,200,100

Array(+(3332+"")[0]).join(".").split(".").map(function(_,i){ return (i+1)*Math.pow(10,(3332+"").length-1);}); //1000,2000,3000
```

Comment: Here is a one liner just to show possibility: `new Array((8321/1000) | 0).join(".").split(".").map(function(_,i){ return (i+1)*1000});`, but seriously, use a simple for loop, it's much more readable.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum, yeah your function is great. But if `getArrForNum(300)` , `1000` is replaced with `100`. So how can we determine whether it is thousand or hundred here. I want `1000` is a dynamic value.

Comment: This function produces wrong result for `20`. `getArrForNum(20)` gives `[10]`, where it should actually produce `[20, 10]`.

Comment: @kadaj That's unspecified in the criteria of OP and can be easily modified to include the number 20 by changing the bound of the for loop (iterate until it's less than or equal, not just less than).

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum, I think it should be `for(var i=1;i*mulOf10 <= num;i++){` here, so if we call `getArrForNum(3000)` then it will return `1000, 2000, 3000`

Comment: @Nothing Yes, this is what I said in my previous comment :)

Answer (score 2):

The following will do what you require:

```
    function getArray(value) {

        var valueOrder = Math.floor( Math.log(value)  / Math.log(10) );
        var result = [];
        var step = Math.pow (10, valueOrder);
        var currentValue = step;

        while (currentValue < value) {
            result.push (currentValue);
            currentValue += step;
        }

        return result.reverse();    
    }
```

Demonstration here: http://jsfiddle.net/5zXc5/

```
    getArray(8939) => 8000,7000,6000,5000,4000,3000,2000,1000
    getArray(340) => 300,200,100
```

You haven't mentioned edge cases (e.g. 1000), but those can be handled easily enough by altering the `<` to a `<=` in the `while`, or adjusting the call to `Math.floor`.

Answer (score 2):

```
function f(a) {
    var len = a.toString().length,
        m = Math.pow(10, len - 1),
        e = a.toString().charAt(0),
        num = e * m,
        i = 1
        out = [];
    for (i = 0; i < e; i++) {
      out.push(num - i * m);
    }
    return out;
}

f(8939); // [8000, 7000, 6000, 5000, 4000, 3000, 2000, 1000]  
f(340);  // [300, 200, 100]  
f(0);    // []
f(10);   // [10]
f(20);   // [20, 10]
f(70);   // [70, 60, 50, 40, 30, 20, 10]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function g(n){
    var p = Math.floor(Math.log(n)/Math.log(10)), // n.toString().length - 1 is cool (in others' answers).
        m = Math.pow(10,p),
        d = Math.floor(n/m),
        r = [];
    for(; d>0; d--){
        r.push(d*m);
    }
    return r;
}

g(8939); // [8000, 7000, 6000, 5000, 4000, 3000, 2000, 1000]
```

Comment: Just a fun fact, you can use `Math.LN10` instead of `Math.log(10)`

Answer (score 1):

```
function mine(num){
var result =[];
var count  = 0;
var i = num;
var f;
while(i!=0){
i = Math.floor(i/10);
count++;
}
f = Math.floor(num/Math.pow(10,count-1));
for(i =f;i>=1 && count>1;i--){
result.push(i*Math.pow(10,count-1));
}
return result;
}
```

mine(8939);     // [8000, 7000, 6000, 5000, 4000, 3000, 2000, 1000]
mine(340);      // [300, 200, 100]
mine(0);       // []
mine(10);      // [10]
mine(20);     // [20, 10]
mine(70);     // [70, 60, 50, 40, 30, 20, 10]